# My A-Frame isn't rendering while my Javascript function is running. How can I have it render simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, aframe, webvr

Using Mozilla's `A-Frame` for WebVR, I try to edit one object's y-position with javascript. However, nothing shows up on the web page until my javascript is done running. Why isn't it simultaneous?

This is my HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello, World! - A-Frame</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Hello, World! - A-Frame">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
      <a-assets>
        <a-asset-item id="crate-obj" src="./aztec-temple.obj"></a-asset-item>
        <a-asset-item id="crate-mtl" src="./aztec-temple.mtl"></a-asset-item>
      </a-assets>
      <a-obj-model src="#crate-obj" mtl="#crate-mtl"></a-obj-model>
      <a-sphere id="comet" position="1, 5.25, -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"></a-sphere>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
  <script src="./main.js"></script>
</html>
```

and my Javascript:

```
function initialCometSetup() {
  var x = 0, y = 5.25, z = -5;
  var myComet = document.getElementById('comet');
  myComet.setAttribute('position', {x: x, y: y, z: z});
  console.log(myComet);
  setTimeout(100, changeZofComet());
}

function changeZofComet() {
    console.log("got here")
    var myComet = document.getElementById('comet');
    var myPos = myComet.getAttribute('position');
    console.log(myPos.y)
    myPos.y = myPos.y - 0.01;
    myComet.setAttribute('position', myPos);
    if (myPos.y > 0) {
        setTimeout(1000, changeZofComet());
    } else {
        console.log("schmuguwuga")
    }
}

setTimeout(1000, initialCometSetup());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating your own rendering loop you should create a component and use the `tick` method to insert your logic into aframe's rendering loop. https://aframe.io/docs/0.3.0/core/component.html#methods